# Mandatory re-install on scope change?

Tags: slack-api

We built a slack app, got it approved in the marketplace, etc. Now we want to add more functionality which will require us to add a scope. The question is - what will happen to the existing app installations? Will the app stop working for them once the new scope is approved? We couldn't find any description of how this is supposed to behave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existing installations will continue to work as they always had and won't be disrupted by the changes you make to your app. They also won't have the new scopes unless the app is re-installed. If your app has the ability to DM users who have installed your app already, if might be good to DM those users and prompt them to re-install so they get the full experience of your app.

Comment: Do you happen to know where is this documented?

Comment: https://api.slack.com/start/distributing/directory#updating